# CG start to collecting garbage too early

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm, heap-memory

I had heap 6g and gc always started to work at ~4.5g heap load.
Now i set -Xmx20g (20 gigabytes heap size) and -Xms16g (initial heap size at 16 gigabytes), but as before, GC activating at ~4.5g memory. 
Why, and how to force gc to use all this memory? 
GC is standard. Java 8.
[image]

Comment: Could you share the actual sizes of Young and Old generations?
It seems that you experience young gen collections although it's not clear why the "threshold" didn't change after bumping the heap space from 6GB to 20GB (especially if you don't set young gen size explicitly).
Also, which GC do you use?

Comment: It'd be best to actually look at GC logs and share relevant portions here.

Comment: let me ask you this - 1) _why_ do you care about this? 2) *Why, and how to force gc to use all this memory* -what do you mean by this?

Comment: Most likely the young generation is ~4.5 GB. try adding `-Xmn16g`, though this might not be good for your application.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try using -Xms20G and -Xmx20G to avoid resizing. Importantly, each time the JVM is resized a full GC is executed so avoiding this process is a good way to minimize the number of full garbage collections.

Please read this

"When a Hotspot JVM starts, the heap, the young generation and the perm generation space are allocated to their initial sizes determined by the -Xms, -XX:NewSize, and -XX:PermSize parameters respectively, and increment as-needed to the maximum reserved size, which are -Xmx, - XX:MaxNewSize, and -XX:MaxPermSize. The JVM may also shrink the real size at runtime if the memory is not needed as much as originally specified. However, each resizing activity triggers a Full Garbage Collection (GC), and therefore impacts performance. As a best practice, we recommend that you make the initial and maximum sizes identical"

Source: http://www.oracle.com/us/products/applications/aia-11g-performance-tuning-1915233.pdf

If you could provide your gc.log, it would be useful to analyse this case thoroughly.

Best regards, RCC

Answer (score 0):

Really! Problem was in eden space. It was automatically set to 6Gb on -Xms16g.
I analyze that my app had low size of long life object, so i have tuned edem to 16g, max heap to 20g and GC activating less often.
[image]

[image]